# how to map json to interface in angular7?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm using angular7 and I want to map a json to my interface.
I need a function to map json fields with the interface and also if the value of json not compatible to inteeface returns error.

```
export interface User {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  phoneNumber: number;
};

const json = {
  firstName: 'Paresh',
  lastName: 'Gami',
  phoneNumber: 'num'
};
```

In my example the type of phone number is not assignable to interface. I want to know how i can manage bad data

Comment: Interfaces are a compile time construct. They do not exist at runtime and are meant to describe the structure of an object. In TS, interfaces are implicitly implemented. Hence, any object that fits the interface is of that type without needing you to do anything explicitly. Your code is already correct and your json is of type User.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @pascalpuetz stated, Typescript interfaces are not existing in runtime. TS will be compiled into JS and you know, JS is a very dynamic language that an object doesnt have a type and can be changed dynamically at anytime.

If you still need to map, you need to add a class and map the properties:

```
export interface IUser {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  phoneNumber: number;
};

export class User implements IUser {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  phoneNumber: number;

  constructor(json: IUser) {
    this.firstName = json.firstName;
    this.lastName = json.lastName;
    this.phoneNumber = json.phoneNumber;
  }
}


const json = {
  firstName: 'Paresh',
  lastName: 'Gami',
  phoneNumber: 'num'
};

...

const result = new User(json);
```

In case of assigning certain json, like:

```
const result = new User({
   firstName: 'Paresh',
   lastName: 'Gami',
   phoneNumber: 'num'
});
```

Typescript will show an error already that the type of a property `phoneNumber` is not assignable.
But in case of assigning anonymous json, like:

```
const json: IUser = await fetch('someurl');
const result = new User(json);
```

This just works and during the runtime(after compliation to JS), it will not consider wheather the json has correct properties or not.

JavaScript will assign the properties whatever the json has. So you have to compare the type of the properties yourself.

```
constructor(json: IUser) {
    if (typeof json.firstName === 'string') {
        this.firstName = json.firstName;
    } else {
        throw 'Bad Data';
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: In my example the type of phone number is not assignable to interface. I want to know how i can manage bad data

Answer (score 0):

```
export interface User {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  phoneNumber: number;
};

const json = {
  firstName: 'Paresh',
  lastName: 'Gami',
  phoneNumber: 'num'
};

var result:User = {};// initialize your result as an empty object of type "User"(interface)
```

then,

```
result = {
  firstName: json.firstName,
  lastName: json.lastName,
  phoneNumber: json.phnoeNumber
 }; // Map your json data to your result
```